# Is there a way to retrace previous conversation between characters in transcript?

Tags: watch-dogs-2

In GTA series you normally can retrace the conversation between characters in the pause menu. I'd love to have this option in Watch Dogs 2 as well, since I'm showing subtitles in a language I'm currently learning, and I'd like to see words I previously missed/didn't understand. Is there a way to do so?